# Shiny Uploading Issues

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I am trying to publish an Shiny app at the moment but I am but after the deployment is completed an the app is loaded in the window, I get an error message of *ERROR: object 'inData' not found*.
In *srcfile.R* I am loading a .csv file which creates *inData* and then doing some analysis which I will use in Shiny to plot. This is my first time actually uploading an app to the server so I am unsure whether the issue is with the app really not finding the input *inData* or there is another error somewhere and this error message is thrown up. I have *srcfile.R* in the folder I uploaded as well as the .csv file that reads from.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

source("srcfile.R")

###########Shiny Starts here#########

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

options(scipen=5)

switcher <- function(x) {
 if(x=="dis"){

#more code below of course.......
```

I have seen that relative pathways are always recommended but maybe I should try an absolute pathway.

Comment: Just to add, in RStudio if I run the _source("srcfile.R")_ line before I hit the run app button it works fine but if I don't manually run _source("srcfile.R")_ then run the app, I get the same error. Putting the _source("srcfile.R")_ call in the shinyServer doesn't help and gives me the same problem. Am I calling the data incorrectly from within the app?

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: I found the issue! Even if your server.R file looks incredibly complicated compared to your ui.R file, never forget that an app ending error can be lurking in that ui.R..........